# Difference between Validator facade Vs Validate() method in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

For Laravel 5.1 we know we can do validation by this way:

#### Validation using validate() method

```
$this->validate( $request, $rules);
```

#### Validation using Validator Facade

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if($validator->fails()) {
  return redirect()->back()
    ->withInput($request->except('password'))
    ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Does redirect back with errors with input required if I use validate() method ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Using `$this->validate( $request, $rules)` make the work for you redirecting the request if rules fails attaching the errors. In the other hand, using `Validator::` makes you to implement a manual redirection.

I suggest you to use a `Form Request class` in order to keep your code clear and reusable.

```
class SignInRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => array('required'),
        ];
    }
}
```

So, in your controller you can do:

```
function validateSignIn(SignInRequest $request){
    // do stuff here if rules are ok
}
```